# Replacing receptacles

Tags: wiring

I have a 40A 240V circuit which currently is wired to a 240V 50A receptacle. I would like to run 2 240V, 20A appliances on this circuit.. Is there anything that prevents me from Wiring up 2 20A 240V receptacles to this circuit?

Comment: Are these appliances cord-and-plug connected or hardwired? Can you turn the breaker for the existing circuit off, remove the receptacle, and shoot us a photo of the inside of the receptacle's junction box, please?

Comment: The breaker MUST be changed code allows a 40 amp breaker in 40 and 50 amp receptacles.. I don’t have the code reference but it has been this way a long time just like a 15 amp duplex receptacle is legal on a 20 amp circuit same table and the only exceptions like this.

Comment: @Ed Beal, maybe you meant allows 40 and 50 amp breakers on 50 amp receptacles?

Comment: @nosparksplease ,, Read the table you posted !!! no I meant exactly a 40 amp breaker can support  a 40 / 50 amp receptacle and that is what the text says I posted as the table you posted after I said that grasshopper. I ask my apprentices these simple questions daily maybe you should get your supervisor to do the same so you can understand the code!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Code prevents you from doing this. On the surface you'd think you can pigtail the #8 wire to #12 (because #8 won't fit in 20 Amp outlets) and connect the #12 to 20 Amp outlets. But the 40 Amp breaker has to be changed out to a 20 AMP breaker because the breaker can't exceed the rating of the wire/outlets attached to it so you'd be limited to using one appliance at a time.The wire might have to be pigtailed into the breaker if it doesn't fit. If these are kitchen appliances on counter tops then the outlets would need to be GFCI protected. If the existing wiring is in conduit, you might think about running two 20 Amp circuits.

Comment: I almost agree but if the breaker is changed there are blue or blue gray wirenuts that can pigtail at the receptacle end but the breaker might not need this depending on brand and type.

Comment: @EdBeal  I edited my answer to add possibly pigtailing the wire into the breaker.

Comment: I would not keep the last sentence but it won’t hurt ( the wire is there)  but it now would be legal according to the NEC +

Answer (score 1):

You can do it but there are a couple of things you need to do. First change that breaker to a 20 amp, depend on brand you may be able to just stick the wires in the breaker terminals and torque them down if not a 12 awg pigtail will be needed again installed to the proper torque. Now at the receptacle or outlet it depends on the box size or wire fill as you will need to pigtail here and from memory a 4x4 box with a single raised 20 amp receptacle might make it legal but I have not run the numbers. If it is larger than a 4 square with a mud ring and pigtailed you will be fine at least under the 2017 NEC . Wow I must be tired I was just thinking about this answer, if your original install was legal a pigtail to a smaller wire size at the receptacle will still be legal with a 20amp 240 v outlet.

Comment: Good catch on the wire possibly not fitting in the 20 AMP breaker.+

Comment: And we really don’t have to worry about a pig tail from the larger wire to a 12 gauge in the panel , this is totally legal where the NEC is the regulating agency.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other answers...

### Why 20A receptacles can only be on a 20A breaker

Receptacle sizes seem pretty arbitrary, don't they?   Here's the Code proper:

> [image]

- There are two exceptions in Code.  You've already met the "50A socket on 40A circuit" exception;  that exists because 40A receptacles *don't* exist.
- The other exception is so you can use common 15A receptacles on 20A kitchen circuits; UL already requires all 15A receps be rated for 20A internally.

There are exceptions covered in 210.19(A), but they require a hardwired connection.

Answer (score -1):

NEC 210.21(B)(3) Receptacle Ratings. Where connected to a branch circuit supplying two or more receptacles or outlets, receptacle ratings shall conform to the values listed in Table 210.21(B)(3), or where rated higher than 50 amperes, the receptacle rating shall not less than the branch circuit rating.

(Then there are exceptions for welders and lighting.)

[image: Table210.212(B)(3)]

If you are talking about household cooking appliances you could hard wire them.

210.19(A)(3)Household Ranges and Cooking Appliances. Branch circuit conductors supplying household ranges, wall-mounted ovens, or counter-mounted cooking units,and other household cooking appliances shall have an ampacity not less than the rating of the branch circuit and not less than the maximum load to be served. For ranges of 8¾kW or more, the minimum branch circuit ampere rating shall be 40 ampere.

210.19(A)(3)Exception No. 1: Conductors tapped from a 50-ampere
branch circuit supplying electric ranges, wall-mounted electric ovens, and counter-mounted electric cooking units shall have an ampacity of not less than 20 amperes and shall be sufficient for the load to be served. These tap conductors include any conductors that are a part of the leads supplied with the appliance that are smaller than the branch-circuit conductors. The taps shall not be longer than necessary for servicing the appliance.

Comment: Not true a receptacle cannot have more than 150% OCPD a hard wired device  oops most branch circuits are limited to 80% , having phone edit issues ,, well a motor circuit can break this rule but not an appliance unless it is covered under article 430 if memory serves.

Comment: I have tried 3x to edit that comment , might be my connection, this can be done with very minor changes if the box at the receptacle Is large enough see my answer hope this one works

Comment: Exactly what I said in my answer but did not have the code reference handy, I edited my answer only because if it was legal with the original receptacle it would still be with a 20 amp. This is not a tap from the op statement! And you have not addressed the max 150%. You can totally change your answer as you have but this only gets a bad view from me as those that only wait for 3 pros to post and then makes a fancy answer!

Comment: Where do you get 150%?

Comment: Try looking in code there is a maximum I have referenced it on several answers but after you totally changed your answer after looking up what I said search the code or my posts. At least my apprentices give credit when I remind them !